# Make colorscheme change when background change

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, lua, background

I have a shortcut to set the background light, dark, or transparent. I want to use a different color scheme for when it is dark or light.

How would I go about implementing it?

I don't know programming and this is my failed try.

```lua
if vim.cmd("set background") == "background=light" then
    vim.cmd("colorscheme modus-operandi")
end
```

I think I need something like [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19435/how-to-set-if-else-for-vims-set-background-for-light-and-dark-colorschemes), but in `lua`.

[Here](https://github.com/enrico223/.config/tree/main/nvim) is my config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```lua
if vim.o.background == 'dark' then
    print("dark")
    vim.cmd("colorscheme modus-vivendi")
    -- vim.cmd("colorscheme dracula")
else
    print('light')
    vim.cmd("colorscheme modus-operandi")
    -- vim.cmd("colorscheme gruvbox")
end

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({"OptionSet"}, {
    pattern = {"background"},
    callback = function(ev)
        if vim.o.background == 'dark' then
            print('late dark')
            vim.cmd("colorscheme modus-vivendi")
            -- vim.cmd("colorscheme dracula")
        else
            print('late light')
            vim.cmd("colorscheme modus-operandi")
            -- vim.cmd("colorscheme gruvbox")
        end
        -- force a full redraw:
        vim.cmd("mode")
    end
})
```

Comment: Just tried it, does not work.

Comment: Are you sure it is executed? Is the background set when it is executed or it set after? Maybe it need to be part of an autocmd.

Comment: Surely there's a better way to get the option value… maybe `vim.o.bg` or something? Anyway, see `:help OptionSet`

Comment: I put it in `init.lua`, and when I start nvim, I get `echo &background` as output in the "command section" (the one under the status line). So I am fairly confident it is being executed.

Comment: But when it is executed, is the colorscheme already loaded (if modus-operandi is a plugin is the plugin already declared)? Is the code before are after the `Plug` command?

Comment: Yes, the colorscheme is already loaded. I think. I updated the question with my `config`, in case that helps.

Comment: I would try to add the `require('plugins')` before your test to make sure the `colorscheme` is available to vim before you set it.

Comment: If I add `require('plugins')`, nvim spits out `module 'plugins' not foud` of course. where should I add it?

Comment: Sorry I was too fast. The `require('enrico')` should be enough :-|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145153/discussion-between-enrico223-and-vivian-de-smedt).